# iOS: Using Accelerate Framework to append / remove a column or row from a matrix?

Tags: objective-c, matrix, accelerate-framework

I've looked through the [vDSP](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009464) and [BLAS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/BLAS_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009457) reference docs, and can't seem to find anything on appending / removing a row or column from a matrix. I'm currently using for-loops, but would rather use an accelerate function if one exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use vDSP_mmov([1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_mmov)) or vDSP_mmovD([2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_mmovD)). Below sample to append 1 row at end.

```
//sanple to add 1 row
float dst[4][4] = { 1,2,3,4, 5,6,7,8, 9,10,11,12 } ; //last row empty
float src[1][4] = { 13,14,15,16 };
//to fill last row
int numColumnsToCopy = 4;
int numRowsToCopy = 1;
int numColsinDst = 4; 
int numColsinSrc = 4;
vDSP_mmov(src, &dst[3][0], numColumnsToCopy, numRowsToCopy, numColsinSrc, numColsinDst );
```

The same sample could be tweaked to append/remove rows/columns at the end. Though you could overwrite rows/columns in middle, I am not sure if you could append/remove a row/column in *middle* of matrix as that will need *shifts*. You might need to split then.

Though there is no harm in using for one off runs, you might not get  speed benefits you are looking for. For repetitive runs, these frameworks help.

Comment: Aww thanks Kiran! I can't believe I missed that. Let me see what I can do!